# Slide a UIViewController onto another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that is currently presented in my iPhone App, and I have a second ViewController that I display when the user taps a button.

However, I'd like to change it. I'd like it to be such that when the user slides their finger, the second view controller appears on the right side, as if the user was sliding through the photos in the native Photos app.

How can I do this? Let's assume the second UIViewController is already created and allocated, just not displayed. I imagine I need to

```
1) Determine when the user is sliding their finger using some touchesBegan function
2) Somehow display only a portion of the second view controller as the user slides their finger across.
```

Any ideas for either of these? I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'd probably want to do is use a `UIScrollView` with its `pagesEnabled` property set to `YES`. This is how Apple's Weather app is implemented.

Then, for each page of the scrollview, you'd add a view controller's view as a subview of the scrollview (by setting the frames properly, so they don't all stack up on one another!).

Comment: +1 - this is the way to go.  Note that if you have a large number of UIViewControllers, you may need to be smart about keeping only some in memory at any one time (current, previous, next).  This will start to become very complicated though, as you'll want to have the new controller instantiation on a background thread to enable your UI to be smooth.  Ultimately you need to ask yourself whether this is worth the extra pain, or you could simply use a `UINavigationController` and `setViewControllers:animated:` with a Swipe Gesture Recognizer to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `UIPageViewController`.  It sounds like that's the class you are looking for.  ([Docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html))

Comment: will this allow me to achieve what I want without the little blue dots on the bottom of the screen, which is what @jbrennan's solution is?

Comment: @jbrennan's solution does not create the 'little blue dots'.  The blue dots are created using a `UIPageControl` class.  The `UIPageViewController` would be the way to go, except for the fact that the only supported transition is PageCurl (ala iBooks) - and not the sliding style required in the question.  +1 for @jbrennan's solution, it's the same route I went down in my own app.

Comment: UIPageViewController does support the sliding style of transition. Take a look at Apple's PhotoScroller example code.

Comment: as of iOS6, UIPageViewControl also (optionally) provides the "little blue dots".

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to slide UIView from Bottom to Top :

```
 myViewController *obj = [[myViewController alloc] init];
 [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```